# How to get multiple class names in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with bs4 in python, in the following code, I want to know the second class name from the tag

HTML code:

```
<span class="type Manhwa"></span>
```

so I wrote this

```
contendorTipo = BeautifulSoup('<span class="type Manhwa"></span>', 'html.parser')
tipo = contendorTipo.p['class']
```

In the bs4 documentation example (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes) it is written like this

So I expect the console to print an array with 2 values (type and Manhwa) or a string with the two classes, but instead I see the following error in the console

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

pls, help me! x'd

Comment: You have `span` tag in your code and in your second line your using `p` tag so how it will going to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `p` tag you should use `span` tag in your to get `classes`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
contendorTipo = BeautifulSoup('<span class="type Manhwa"></span>', 'html.parser')
classes = contendorTipo.span['class']

classes
```

Output:

```
['type', 'Manhwa']
```